# Full outer join doesn't returns the results from right table

Tags: sql, postgresql

My application has a list of users who can be booked for a bookings. We need to pay the users for these bookings. I need to get the list of users who needs to be paid. A user can be paid if they have bookings or with payment created which has no bookings.

I tried the below:

```
SELECT 
  users.id as user_id,
  user_bookings.id as user_booking_id,
  user_bookings.payment_id as user_booking_payment_id,
  payments.id as payment_id
FROM 
  users 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_bookings ON user_bookings.user_id = user.id 
  FULL JOIN payments ON payments.id = user_bookings.payment_id

Where payments.issued = false;
```

But it doesn't list the users with the payment with no bookings. It only lists the users with the bookings created. How can I get the users with payment which doesn't have any bookings?

**EDIT**

I tried the below query:

User with 37271 has the below payment records:

```
 select payments.id, payments.issued from payments where payments.user_id=37271;

   id   | issued 
--------+--------
 133046 | f
 133045 | t
(2 rows)
```

Below are the bookings I have:

```
select user_bookings.id, user_bookings.payment_issued, user_bookings.payment_id from user_bookings where user_id=37271;

   id   | payment_issued    | payment_id 
--------+-------------------+---------------
 541136 | t                 |        133045
 541137 | t                 |        133045
(2 rows)
```

While running the below query:

```
SELECT u.id as user_id, ub.id as user_booking_id, ub.payment_id as user_booking_payment_id,
       p.id as payment_id, p.issued as payments_issued
FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN
     user_bookings ub
     ON ub.user_id = u.id FULL JOIN
     (SELECT p.*
      FROM payments p
      WHERE NOT p.issued
     ) p
     ON p.id = ub.payment_id

where users.id=37271;
```

It doesn't returns the payment with no bookings but it returns issued payments:

```
 user_id | user_booking_id | user_booking_payment_id | payment_id | payments_issued 
---------+-----------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------
   37271 |          541137 |                  133045 |            | 
   37271 |          541136 |                  133045 |            | 
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  users.id as user_id,
  user_bookings.id as user_booking_id,
  user_bookings.payment_id as user_booking_payment_id,
  payments.id as payment_id,
FROM 
  users 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_bookings ON user_bookings.user_id = user.id 
  FULL JOIN payments ON payments.id = linguist_bookings.payment_id

Where payments.issued = false
   OR payments.issued IS NULL;
```

If you use an outer join, you turn it into an inner join if you use it in a `WHERE` clause; because `NULL = [something]` is never true.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It doesn't work after adding a condition with Null too.

Answer (score 0):

You are turning the outer `join` into an `inner join`.  Dealing with filtering with `full outer join` is tricky.  I recommend a subquery:

```
SELECT u.id as user_id, ub.id as user_booking_id, ub.payment_id as user_booking_payment_id
       p.id as payment_id,
FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN
     user_bookings ub
     ON ub.user_id = u.id FULL JOIN
     (SELECT p.*
      FROM payments p
      WHERE NOT p.issued
     ) p
     payments p
     ON p.id = ub.payment_id;
```

I would, however, question why you want a `FULL JOIN` here.  You could get payment ids with no other information from the other tables.

I would expect a `LEFT JOIN` to be sufficient:

```
SELECT u.id as user_id, ub.id as user_booking_id, ub.payment_id as user_booking_payment_id,
       p.id as payment_id
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     user_bookings ub
     ON ub.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN
     payments p
     ON p.id = ub.payment_id AND NOT p.issued;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have used FULL JOIN since I need to get the users with bookings needs to be paid for which payment haven't created yet and need to get the payment which doesn't have bookings at all. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Also, The above subquery doesn't work as well. I am not sure what I did wrong. Updated the question with the result I got.

Comment: @Gomathi . . . The last query should return all users and their bookings, which you can filter down to a particular user if you want.